Image localisation and georeference
I wonder if i could successfully georeference an image from lens exif data and Google Earth or any other similar mapping software. The exif metadata contains NO GPS data. The image contains features with measurable dimensions such as hills and mountains (height) or distance between islands. The approximate position and general direction of the camera is known. All i want is maximum positional accurancy if possible.

The image contains known or unknown features? Known meaning you know which mountain, hill, island is which, their name, coordinates and all.

Can you clarify with an example of how precisely the position is already known, and how much more precision you want? Without context it's hard to tell if "approximate position" means "what country it's in" or "which street intersection it's at"

This question is similar to: How can I figure out precisely where someone was standing to take this old cityscape photograph?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

For maximum accuracy, you don't want trigonometry. What you want is a technique used in piloting:

you find two things that are aligned (say, a house and the top of hill) which puts you on a straight line that goes through these two points, that you can draw on the map
repeat above for another pair of things, that gives you a second linen that you can draw on the map.
the camera was at the intersection of the two lines
you can be more accurate with a third pair (the size of the triangle tells you how accurate you are)


What does the last sentence between parentheses mean?

@SaaruLindestøkke, when you have 3 lines on surface they make triangle. In above case if the coordinates are absolutely precise this triangle will be dot. If not so precise this will be triangle and the size of this triangle will tell you how big the inaccuracy is

@SaaruLindestøkke, maybe this draw can clarify a bit :) https://imgur.com/a/qlLCOi4  The left is accurate coordinates, the right is inaccurate

Building on xenoid's answer: this technique is called trilateration, and it's good to know if you ever spend time in remote areas for wayfinding (I'd recommend learning it if you do landscape photography, especially for locations that require camping or hiking for a while on backcountry trails).
If you'd like to do a really deep dive into how this technique is used by modern GNSS (think, GPS) systems, Bartosz Ciechanowski's blog has an excellent longform writeup about that here. It's got visualizations that can help add some intuition to the idea that a triangular area where trilateration lines should intersect represents error.

+1 for the interactive animations in that blog link!
